Не работает фильтр по дате в методе GetList() в 1С-Битрикс
Я пытаюсь получить количество элементов в информационном блоке в 1С-Битрикс, используя метод GetList() класса CIBlockElement. Однако, когда я пытаюсь применить фильтр по дате, используя параметры >=DATE_ACTIVE_FROM и <=DATE_ACTIVE_TO, данные не приходят в указанном промежутке времени.
<!--получаем количество элементов в инфоблоке-->
<?php
function numProductInfoblock($ID_INFOBLOCK)
{
    CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");

    $currentDate = date('d.m.Y'); // Текущая дата

    // массив, который содержит фильтры для выборки элементов информационного блока в 1С-Битрикс.
    $arFilter = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $ID_INFOBLOCK, // ID информационного блока
        "ACTIVE" => "Y", // статус активности элемента
        '>=DATE_ACTIVE_FROM' => $currentDate,
        '<=DATE_ACTIVE_TO' => $currentDate,
    );

    $el = new CIBlockElement;
    $responseInfoBlock = $el->GetList(
        array(), // пустой массив, передаваемый в качестве параметра $arOrder.
        $arFilter, // массив фильтров для выборки элементов. Он передается в качестве второго параметра метода GetList()
        false, // значение для параметра $bIncCnt, которое указывает на отключение подсчета количества элементов.
        false, // значение для параметра $arNavStartParams, которое указывает на отсутствие параметров навигации.
        array("ID") // массив полей, которые необходимо выбрать. В данном случае, мы выбираем только поле "ID" для каждого элемента.
    ); // После выполнения метода GetList(), результат выборки будет сохранен в переменную $responseInfoBlock. Этот результат является объектом CIBlockResult, который можно использовать для получения информации о выбранных элементах

    return $countElements = $responseInfoBlock->SelectedRowsCount(); // получаем количество элементов в инфоблоке
}

У меня есть товары в инфоблоке с датами 10.08.2024 - 25.08.2024 (Текущая дата 19.08.2024). Ни один из товаров не попадает в выборку, в чем может быть причина? Дату передаю в следующем формате
У товаров стоит активность и если делать фильтрацию только по этому параметру, то все работает корректно.
В административной панели битрикса проверил настройки даты Настройки->Настройки продукта->Языковые параметры->Языки интерфейса формат даты DD.MM.YYYY
У каждого элемента дата выводится корректно.

У вас точно указаны поля "Дата начала активности" и "Дата окончания активности"?

@rusgeli - да конечно

Вы перепутали знаки >= и <= в фильтре.

@ВикторКарев, да вы правы, спасибо большое
